# Detecting common colors for groups of objects

Tags: opencv, colors, computer-vision

I have an image with a collection of objects in K given perceived colors. Providing I extract those objects, how could I cluster them by their perceived color?

Let me give you an example. I am trying to cluster two football teams - so there will be two teams, referees and a keeper (or two, but that`s a rare situation) on the image - 3, 4 or 5 clusters.

[image: pitch]

For a human's eye, it`s an easy situation. On the picture above, we have white players, red players and a black ref. But it turns out not so easy for automatic processing.

What I have tried so far:

1) I've started working on the BGR colorspace, then tried HSV and now I am exploring CIE Luv, as I read it has unified distances describing the perceived differences between colors.

2) [BGR and HSV] taking the most common color from the contour (not the bounding box). this didn' work at all because of the noise (green field getting in the way), the quality of the image, the position of the player, etc. Colors were pretty much random.

3) [CIE Luv] Resizing all players' boxes to a common size and taking a small portion of the image from the middle (as marked by a black rectangle in the example below).

[image: player]

Taking the mean value of all pixels in each player's window  and adding to the list (so, it`s one pixel with the mean value per player). Using K-means (with a defined number of clusters) to find out clusters on that list. This has proven somewhat successful, for the image above I have redish, white and blackish centres in the clusters.

[image: clusters]

Unfortunately, the assignment of players back to these clusters is pretty much random. I am doing that by calculating the mean color for each player like I described above and then measuring the distance to each cluster. A player might be assigned to the white cluster on one frame and to the red one on the next. Part of the problem might be that the window in the middle of the player's box will sometimes catch a number, grass or shorts, instead of the jersey.

I have already spent a considerable amount of time on trying to figure that out, grateful for any help.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand as it does not contain any code samples, but from what I understand is that you had created a list containing mean pixel values of CIE Luv colorspace and had applied KMeans on it. Now after you have created the clustering model you need to know which value is in which cluster. Is that right? If this is so then just loop over the list and use the model created to predict which cluster each pixel would lie in. You will need to create a dictionary of `player: mean pixel value` first so that you trace it back to the player with its cluster.

Comment: I think it's more of a method/algorithm question, rather than exact code. The main point (regardless of what I've done so far - the right answer may be completely different) is how do I flawlessly cluster players to the appropriate number of colored clusters. On the image above you`d have 3 of them, white, red and black.

Answer (score 0):

I may be overcomplicating the problem since you just have 3 classes, but try training an SVM classifier based on HOG descriptors. maybe try LDA to improve speed

Some references -

1] http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.627.6465&rep=rep1&type=pdf - skip to recognition part

2] https://rodrigob.github.io/documents/2013_ijcnn_traffic_signs.pdf - skip to recognition part.

3] https://www.learnopencv.com/handwritten-digits-classification-an-opencv-c-python-tutorial/ - if you want to jump into the code right away

This will always work as long as your detection is good. and can also help to identify different players  based on their shirt number 
(maybe more???) if you train it right

EDIT: Okkay I have another idea, based on colour segmentation since that was your original approach and require less work (maybe not? color segmentation is a pain! also LIGHTING! LIGHTING! LIGHTING!).
Create a green mask and create a threshold so you detect as little grass as possible when doing your kmeans. Then instead of finding mean, try median instead, that will get you closer to red, coz white is detected as 0 and mean just drops drastically, median doesnt. So it'll be way more robust and you should be able to sort players better (hair color and skin color shouldnt affect it too much)

EDIT 2: Just noticed, if you use the black rectangle you'll get shirt number more (which is white), gonna mess up your classifier, use original box with green masked out

EDIT 3: Also. You can just create 3 thresholds for your required colors and split them up! don't really need Kmeans in this actually. Basically you just need your detected boxes to give out a value inside that threshold. Try the median method I mentioned above. Should improve. Also, might need some more minor tweaks here and there (blur, morphology etc to improve detection)

Comment: I haven't checked all the resources/ideas you're offering, but I have a feeling you are referring only to this very situation I gave as example. I need this to be universal, and any ML model without a good training set (which I don't have) will overfit strongly towards this particular case. I also can`t define static thresholds, as you're suggesting. That said, I think some of your ideas are indeed good and I am going to check them over the next days, thanks.

Comment: when you say universal, do you mean more than just these 2 colors? like do you want to detect other teams as well and separate them?

Comment: basically a general model to separate any two teams that are playing and a ref correct?

Comment: Yes, any setup. might be between 3-5 clusters - for two teams, refs and keepers.